# Dragging and dropping like in Puzzle and Dragons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I will graduate a programmer's course this May. Now I'm developing my project. I would like to make copy of Puzzle and Dragons game. I use Unity3d and write code in C#.

I have done random generation of runes on the board, but I have a problem. I don't know how to drag them and swap. The Unity Forum can't help me.

[test run of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvxAO.png)

If you did this or know how to make this, could you please teach me?

Answer (score 1):

1. you need a representation of your rune's grid (a 2d array or a
   list). You need to be able to determine which rune is where so a 2d
   array is probably the most efficient way to handle it.
2. you need to know which rune the user is trying to move, so on the mouse down
   event, using the coordinate of the mouse you have to calculate in
   which row/column the user clicked. Keep the rune in reference
3. on the mouse move, you can calculate over which rune you currently are.
   Only required if you want to do some animation (like a glow effect
   letting know the user which rune would be switched)
4. On mouse up event, you do the actual switch.

Comment: Hello, 1st position i did. I made array [ , ] of objects.
But i don't know all events in Unity =) I'm not pro user of GOOGLE... Q_Q
I will try to do other position that you said.
Thank you, very much!

Comment: I will try to put my code here tomorrow (18-02-2018)